# Print key and value of all items in simple json string to console

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following and I can print out each property. Easy enough, but is there an easy way to print the key and value of each item in the JSON string?  Simply looking to print in console the key and the value.

```
private static void deserializeUserSimple() {
    String userJson = "{\"name\":\"smithy\",\"email\":\"blah@gmail.com\",\"age\":21,\"isDeveloper\":true}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    UserSimple userSimple = gson.fromJson(userJson, UserSimple.class);

     // this prints but looking for easy way to print all key and values
    System.out.println(userSimple.name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String userJson = "{\"name\":\"smithy\",\"email\":\"blah@gmail.com\",\"age\":21,\"isDeveloper\":true}";
JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(userJson, JsonObject.class);
for(String key:convertedObject.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Key - " + key);
            System.out.println("Value - " + convertedObject.get(key));
}
```

Output:

```
Key - name
Value - "smithy"
Key - email
Value - "blah@gmail.com"
Key - age
Value - 21
Key - isDeveloper
Value - true
```